# A popup login page

Tags: javascript, html

I have wrote some code to build a popup login in my index page with JavaScript language (without database). The login page is set with a constant username and password, for example username = xxx and password = nnn in this case.

Below are my codes on index page and the login popup page:

Index page code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/timetabling.css">
        <title>Time-tabling system</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="main">
            <div id="header">
                <div id="widgetBar">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <img align="left" src="logo.jpg" alt="logo" width="300" height="100">
                    </div>
                    <div class="button">
                        <button class="btn login" id="login_button">Login</button>

                        <div class="popup">
                            <div class="popup-content">
                                <img scr="close.png" alt="Close" class="close">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="username">
                                <input type="password" placeholder="password">
                                <button>login</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <script language="javascript" src="login.js"></script>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <img align="center" src="keep-habbit-tracking.jpg" alt="habbit" width="600" height="300">
            <p align="center">Welcome to the time-tabling system!!</p>
            <p align="center">This is a place for you to set your time table and schedule your work...</p>
            <p align="center">Please login to begin</p>

            <div id="footer">
                <hr>
                <p id="footerText">Group 18 The time tabling system</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Code for Popup login page:

```
  document.getElementById("login_button").addEventListener("click", function(){
        document.querySelector(".popup").style.display = "flex";
        })

        document.querySelector(".close").addEventListener("click", function(){
        document.querySelector(".popup").style.diplay = "none";
        })


        var attempt = 3; //Variable to count number of attempts
        function validation(){
            var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
            var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
            if(username === "xxx" && password === "nnn"){
                alert("Login successfully");
                window.location="swap.html";
                return false;
            }
            else{
                attempt--;
                alert("You have left "+attempt+" attempt;");
                if(attempt ===0){
                    document.getElementById("username").disabled=true;
                    document.getElementById("password").disabled=true;
                    document.getElementById("submit").disabled=true;
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

I can show a popup page for user to login with these codes, but I am not able to check the username and password whether it is xxx and nnn. Also the login button in my popup login page can't direct me to another page after I click on it.

Could anyone help on this, I read the code line by line and can't find out any problem. Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLpmw.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to give id attribute in your textfields

```
                     <div class="popup-content">
                        <img scr="close.png" alt="Close" class="close">
                        <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="username">
                        <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="password">
                            <button  onclick="validation()">login</button>
                    </div>
```

Comment: I have tried this, same problem. Maybe the problem is in the JavaScript file, I am weak at JavaScript.

Comment: you didn't call validation() function when login button clicking